# How to access a constant in main.js in another js file in vue.js framework?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `vue.js` application and in the `main.js` file I have configured the `Vuei18n` as per the documentation. This is working perfectly and in order to access this in other components, I have added this to `new Vue()` instance and this is now accessible (with `this.$i18n`).

Now I have created a `validator.js` file for validation rules and I need to use the `this.$i18n` there, but its not working. I have also tried `Vue.prototype.$i18n` but that too not working. Can someone help me to find out where I went wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### exporting the i18n variable

I'll assume your app is a vue-cli app, or at least that you use webpack to build it
and therefore can use ES modules.

Working with vue-i18n you would do something like the following:

```
// step 1: define the i18n object via new Vue18n
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
  messages,
});

// step 2: setup the Vue object to use this object:
new Vue({
 i18n,
 ... store, router.... whatever
})
```

Where `messages` contain all the JSON's with the translations keys and values.

I guess you already are doing something like this.

And now, in your validator module you need the very same `i18n` object you plugged to Vue.

Instead of trying to get to `Vue` in your validator, you can just plain `export` the `i18n` varible from `main.js`:

`export {i18n}`

So, in your `validator.js` file, you can just `import` it:

`import {i18n} from '@/main.js' // or whatever is the path`

This is pretty much how I'm solving the validator internationalization problem in my own application.

#### Important note: circular dependencies

If you're already importing the `validator.js` in your `main.js`, you won't be able to import `i18n` from main in your validator module. To avoid such a problem, you would move the `i18n` initialization and exportation to another module, such as `i18n.js`, so the validator and the main file can `import` it independently.

### Without es6 modules

In case you're not using webpack or another bundler to bundle your code, you can still just export the `i18n` object to the `window` object:

`window.i18n = i18n`

and then use it from whatever file. You just need to be careful to store the `i18n` object in `window` before any file will try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is Custom Events. According to [this documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), you should be able to emit your variable with something like below

```
this.$emit('send-i18n', this.$i18n)
```

Still according to the documentation, try to use `v-on:send-i18n` to retreive your value.

Hope it works.